# Contdown on Servlet Session

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, session-timeout

I need to create a countdown on the servlet´s session to fire events when X minutes to expire...

So, there is a way to know how many seconds is remaining to finish the session?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can compute the remaining time (in seconds) using the [HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) API:

```
httpSession.getMaxInactiveInterval() - ((System.currentTimeMillis() - httpSession.getLastAccessedTime())/1000
```